# If column value contains symbol, retain only the substring after the symbol

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

If `index` column value is separated by `;`, then retain only the substring after the `;`. Else, retain as-is. Would be even better if its in list comprehension.
My code raised `ValueError: Length of values (4402) does not match length of index (22501)`.

```
# If gene name is separated by ";", then get the substring after the ";"
list = []
for i in meth["Name"]:
    if ";" in i:
        list.append(i.split(";",1)[1])
    else:
        continue

meth["Name"] = list
```

Traceback:

```
--> 532             "Length of values "
    533             f"({len(data)}) "
    534             "does not match length of index "

ValueError: Length of values (4402) does not match length of index (22501)
```

Sample data:

`meth.iloc[0:4,0:4].to_dict()`

```
{'index': {0: 'A1BG', 1: 'A1CF', 2: 'A2BP1', 3: 'A2LD1'},
 'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': {0: 0.27891582736223297,
  1: 0.786837244239289,
  2: 0.5310546143038515,
  3: 0.7119161837613309},
 'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': {0: 0.318496987871566,
  1: 0.386177267500376,
  2: 0.5086236274690276,
  3: 0.4036012750884792},
 'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A': {0: 0.400119915667055,
  1: 0.54983504208745,
  2: 0.5352071929258406,
  3: 0.6139719037555759}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to perform this operation on the column names, or to values of a specific column?

Either way, I think this will do the job:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Define the example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'index': {0: 'A1BG', 1: 'A1CF', 2: 'A2BP1', 3: 'A2LD1'},
        'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': {0: 0.27891582736223297, 1: 0.786837244239289,
                             2: 0.5310546143038515, 3: 0.7119161837613309},
        'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': {0: 0.318496987871566, 1: 0.386177267500376,
                             2: 0.5086236274690276, 3: 0.4036012750884792},
        'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A': {0: 0.400119915667055, 1: 0.54983504208745,
                             2: 0.5352071929258406, 3: 0.6139719037555759}
    }
)
# Original dataframe:
df
"""
   index  TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A  TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A  TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A
0   A1BG          0.278916          0.318497          0.400120
1   A1CF          0.786837          0.386177          0.549835
2  A2BP1          0.531055          0.508624          0.535207
3  A2LD1          0.711916          0.403601          0.613972
"""
# Replacing column names, using '-' as separator:

df.columns = df.columns.astype(str).str.split('-').str[-1]

# Modified dataframe:
df
"""
   index       01A       01A       01A
0   A1BG  0.278916  0.318497  0.400120
1   A1CF  0.786837  0.386177  0.549835
2  A2BP1  0.531055  0.508624  0.535207
3  A2LD1  0.711916  0.403601  0.613972
"""
```

You can apply the same logic to your dataframe index, or specific columns:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'index': {0: 'A1BG', 1: 'A1CF', 2: 'A2BP1', 3: 'A2LD1'},
        'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': {0: 0.27891582736223297, 1: 0.786837244239289,
                             2: 0.5310546143038515, 3: 0.7119161837613309},
        'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': {0: 0.318496987871566, 1: 0.386177267500376,
                             2: 0.5086236274690276, 3: 0.4036012750884792},
        'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A': {0: 0.400119915667055, 1: 0.54983504208745,
                             2: 0.5352071929258406, 3: 0.6139719037555759},
        'name': {0: 'A;B;C', 1: 'AAA', 2: 'BBB', 3: 'C-DE'}
    }
)

# Original dataframe:
df
"""
   index  TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A  TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A  TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A   name
0   A1BG          0.278916          0.318497          0.400120  A;B;C
1   A1CF          0.786837          0.386177          0.549835    AAA
2  A2BP1          0.531055          0.508624          0.535207    BBB
3  A2LD1          0.711916          0.403601          0.613972   C-DE
"""

# Splitting values from column "name":

df['name'] = df['name'].astype(str).str.split(';').str[-1]
df
"""
   index  TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A  TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A  TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A  name
0   A1BG          0.278916          0.318497          0.400120     C
1   A1CF          0.786837          0.386177          0.549835   AAA
2  A2BP1          0.531055          0.508624          0.535207   BBB
3  A2LD1          0.711916          0.403601          0.613972  C-DE
"""
```

#### Note

Please note that if the column values hold multiple repetitions of the same separator (e.g.: `"A;B;C"`), only the last substring gets returned (for `"A;B;C"`, returns `"C"`).

Comment: I want to apply to a specific column

Comment: Then the second option might work: `df['name'] = df['name'].astype(str).str.split(';').str[-1]`. Change the value `'name'` to the name of the column you want to perform the operation, and `';'` from `.split` to the correct separator you want to split